# Is it possible to use the dataset generated dynamically in the report viewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, desktop-application

I am new to Windows Desktop Application Development.

I want to print the bill in my application and I have used a report viewer control and placed two labels to display the Bill No and Party Name.

I am creating the dataset in code behind file in C#.

I am assigning the value of dataset cell to the text property of the label. My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection cn;
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Bill\\dbBill.accdb");
        string query = "select A.BillNo,A.BillType,A.TaxType,A.PartyName,B.Desc,B.Desc,B.HSNCode,B.Qty,B.Rate,(B.Qty*B.Rate) as Amount " +
                       "from BillMaster A inner join BillDetail B on B.BillNo=A.BillNo";
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dbBillDataSet.BillDetail' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.BillDetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbBillDataSet.BillDetail);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


    }

    private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        lblBillNo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BillNo"].ToString();
        lblParty.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PartyName"].ToString();
    }
}
}
```

How to assign the dataset values to the controls placed inside the report viewer control.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit more??

Comment: Sure.. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: I want master details to be displayed once. That are BillNo, PartyName,Address & CSTNo. That are stored in BillMaster Table in Access 2007. So I put the labels for that. And the details which belongs to the particular BillNo should be displayed in grid that I am going to place in the same report viewer control. So I want to bind the values from the dataset to the grid and the text properties of the labels. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: it sounds like an invoice. well, i believe the lables will be outside the ReportViewer control. Right?

Comment: No sir lables are inside the report viewer control.

Can I send you my code.?? @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: Yup...post it here. Check my post below as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25672/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-praveen-nambiar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You wont be able to access `DataSet` instance `ds` inside of `reportviewr_load`. I would suggest you to make a `function()` which will return a `DataSet` and use that `function()` inside of the `reportviewr_load`.

Comment: Sir, will you please help me for my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056934/code-for-binding-gridview-works-in-single-form-application-but-not-in-mdi-form-a) query? @Praveen Nambiar

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataSet YourData()
{
cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Bill  \\dbBill.accdb");
string query = "select     
  A.BillNo,A.BillType,A.TaxType,A.PartyName,B.Desc,B.Desc,B.HSNCode,B.Qty,B.Rate,
  (B.Qty*B.Rate) as Amount " +

 "from BillMaster A inner join BillDetail B on B.BillNo=A.BillNo";
 cn.Open();
 cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
 da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 cn.Close();
 return ds;
}
```

Comment: answer suggested by @Praveen Nambiar